# Game Over if all crew dead but have cloning bay?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Regarding the advanced edition of FTL:

If all of your crew dies but you have a cloning bay on your vessel, is it immediately game over, or does the cloning bay prevent that?  Is the game smart enough to know that a damaged cloning bay and a fully dead crew means you cannot recover, but a functional one (even if temporarily without power) could revive your crew?

Also, does this answer differ between hostile ships and your own ship?  (That is, do you get to capture and loot enemy vessels that have all dead crew but have a functional cloning bay?)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've just tested this out by holding a party in a de-pressurised weapons room. The crew seemed to have a great time and, providing the clone bay remained online and powered, all woke up the next morning with only minor hangovers.

By powering down the clone bay, however, as soon as a crewman died I was given a big angry warning saying "Clonebay off - Crew are dying!", despite the fact that I was able to re-assign power to fix this. When the last crewman's DNA was lost, I was given the standard Game Over screen

The clonebay will store a dead crew member's DNA whilst it has power. If it loses power for whatever reason, the warning will sound and you'll have around 4 seconds to restore power or lose that crewman. It does not matter how close they are to reviving, and once power is restored all progress is reset. This probably means it is possible to survive against non-drone non-lanius boarders for extended periods by de-pressurising the entire ship, letting everyone die, then juggling the power in your clone bay to keep your crew in storage, but stop them from reviving -- this idea is not without merit, since it's feasible that the invaders would die before kicking over the clonebay, and it would prevent your crew from constantly respawning and dying again, preserving their stats. Personally, however, if I were in this situation I'd just power down the clonebay and take the quick way out.

I suspect that the same will be true for enemy ships - you can capture and loot as soon as the last crewman's DNA is removed from the clonebay. How the [Backup DNA Bank](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Backup_DNA_Bank) would change this is not clear.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Anyone with verification on this situation with regard to enemy ships will be given a +1 as well.

Comment: I like the idea of a vacuum-party! :D

Comment: @Shaamaan Nah, trust me... those things *suck*!

Answer (score 22):

I have boarded enemy ships with cloning bays, and if their cloning bay remains online and powered, eliminating their crew does not grant victory of the battle. I cannot prove this, beyond my word however.

Comment: That's acceptable enough.  Thank you. +1

Comment: I've found the same thing to be true.  Gotta take out that clone bay, or the battle never ends.

Comment: Unless the purpose is to train your crew in hand to hand... then it can be very useful

Comment: @ChargingPun which is exactly what I did, awesome exploit there.

Comment: @ChargingPun, based on what I've seen recently, I think that bug has been fixed, so that you only get fighting experience once for beating an enemy no matter how many times he clones.

Answer (score 20):

In regard to the backup DNA bank + Clone Bay destroyed + All Crew Dead question... The game doesn't seem to know what to do. I just had it happen by accident and the game is stuck where I can't jump; no game over message.

[image: FTL Screen Grab1]

[image: FTL Screen Grab2]

Received the following from FT Tech Support in response to the above issue:

> "That's a tricky end game state to detect, as there are a lot of ways
>   out of it. If you had a repair drone or repair bomb, then you'd be
>   able to save yourself. Or if you had another crew rewarded after the
>   fight, you could save yourself. So right now we've just left it as an
>   odd state that you have to manually leave. Thanks for the report
>   though."

Comment: Whoa! Who do we report bugs to?

Comment: Good question @BlackVegetable; I'm going to try and find out and report the bug.

Comment: Received the following from FTL tech support:

"That's a tricky end game state to detect, as there are a lot of ways out of it. If you had a repair drone or repair bomb, then you'd be able to save yourself. Or if you had another crew rewarded after the fight, you could save yourself. So right now we've just left it as an odd state that you have to manually leave. Thanks for the report though."

Comment: Hey, that's an excellent bit of information there.  Would you be willing to move it out of your comment and into the main post?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Just added it to my main post.