# Clone bay damaged crew dead but backed up with DNA backup can you continue game?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I was in the format C version of the Rock cruiser and attacked the crew was killed and clone bay damaged had the Backup DNA augmentation. All the crew is suspended waiting to be cloned except there is no one to repair the clone bay! Aside from starting the game over completely is there a way to continue?

Comment: Did it not tell you "game over"? I'm pretty sure you're stuck, so that sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: See this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166514/90537  Basically you can't recover.